# Flink job becomes FINISHED because of an invalid SQL query

Tags: sql, apache-flink

We are running Flink jobs that consume data from Kafka, perform an SQL query (using the SQL API) and write the output to Kafka.

Our jobs are configured to run forever, so they should never be FINISHED (unless they are stopped with a savepoint). However, we have noticed that with some (invalid) SQL queries, the job can start but becomes FINISHED later on. That is the case when we include something like `field <> NULL`. The documentation of Flink says:

> value1 <> value2 Returns TRUE if value1 is not equal to value2; returns UNKNOWN if value1 or value2 is NULL.

It is not clear to us what UNKNOWN is and how the job is expected to react when that happens. In any case, we would expect it to fail instead of finishing silently. Could it be a bug in Flink? Is it the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have upgraded to Flink 1.15 and we can't reproduce the error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL standard defines a three-valued logic system with true, false, and unknown as the possible results of a comparison. Rather than `field <> NULL` you can use `field IS NOT NULL`, which will return true or false.

Comment: We are aware of the correct query (IS NOT NULL) in that case, but that was only an example. Our issue is that the job becomes FINISHED even though it's never supposed to stop, unless explicitly terminated by an external request.

Is that the expected behaviour when an "unknown" is emitted? Or an issue that we should handle in our code?

Comment: Are there any clues in the task manager logs as to why the job stopped running? Perhaps the sink is defined in such a way that it can't accept "unknown"?

Comment: I can't find anything. I see "switched from INITIALIZING to RUNNING." and immediately after I get "Source: (...) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.".
The sink is a FlinkKafkaProducer with a custom KafkaSerializationSchema, but the `serialize` function does not seem to be called. I don't see what could make it stop.

Comment: That sounds like a source ran out of input -- could it be that there is a bounded source?

Comment: The sources are built using a FlinkKafkaConsumer, and registered as a table using tableEnv.fromChangelogStream. They should not be bounded. But maybe there is some kind of optimization happening. Could Flink detect that `field <> NULL` is always UNKNOWN, and decide that there is actually nothing to run, or that no record in the source will ever match (and thus stop the source)?

Comment: I don't think the filter pushdown is that smart, but I'm not sure.